# Measuring client back-up when using Boost.Beast WebSocket

Tags: boost, websocket, boost-asio, boost-beast, beast-websockets

I am reading from a Boost.Beast WebSocket. When my application gets backed up, the websocket sender appears happy to delay/buffer the data on their end (presumably at the application level, as they will delay by 1 minute or more).

What is the best way to measure if I am getting backed up? For example, can I look at the size of a TCP buffer? I could also read all the data into memory in a fast thread, and put it in a queue for the slow thread (in which case, backup can be measured by the size of the queue). But I'm wondering if there's a more direct way.

Comment: You seem to know exactly what you mean by "backed up". I don't think that's common jargon. Can you put in words what you see, and what you think is happening? I *think* in general the queue mechanism /(optionally with/ a protocol feedback feature, like "send fewer requests", or even "this [type of] request will be accepted in n milliseconds") is the correct way to deal with server overload. If you think delays are happening because the IO thread is slowed by non-IO, you could probably separate those

Comment: By "backed up", I mean "queuing" - I'm processing data slower than I'm receiving it. The queuing takes place below my application level - in the inbound TCP buffer. I'm trying to figure out a way to get visibility into this. One way to do this is `boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::available()`, but that function takes about 3us to run, which is slower than I'd prefer. I don't have the ability to tell the sender to slow down at the application level. They seem to slow down when my TCP buffer gets full, but I'm not sure why - packet loss/retrans, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This varies by platform, but there's the SO_RCVBUF option that sets the amount of data that can be queued onto the socket before TCP pauses receiving more data.

If you have access to the socket, `s`, invoke this to inspect how much data its rcv buffer size can hold

```
    net::socket_base::receive_buffer_size opt = {};
    s.get_option(opt);
```

You'll probably see that it defaults to something like 64K or so.

Then crank it up real high to like a megabyte:

```
    net::socket_base::receive_buffer_size optSet(1000000);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    s.set_option(optSet, ec);
```

YMMV on how large of a value you can pass to the set_option call and how much actually helps.

Keep in mind, this is only a temporary measure to relieve the pressure.  If you keep getting backed up, you'll only hit the limit again, just a bit later and perhaps less often.

> I could also read all the data into memory in a fast thread, and put it in a queue for the slow thread

Yes, but you've basically implemented exactly what SO_RCVFROM does. Either that, or you buffer to infinity with respect to memory cost (no limit).